# Poisson distribution: sample size vs rate

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

I was looking at some exercises on Poisson distribution and was confused by the answers. Here are the questions:

- Sam's Party Supplies has had trouble with balloons. Experience has shown that the ones he buys from his present supplier, Rooty Balloons, are 2% defective. Al, representing Tooty Balloons, promises him 1% defectives if he will switch his order to them. Al gives Sam a sample package of 10 Tooty balloons. Sam blows them all up, and one of them turns out to be no good. "Looks to me like we have 10% defectives here," he tells Al. What does Al say in response?
- Sam tries nine more packages of ten balloons each, and all of them are free of defects, except one package which has 1 bad balloon in it. Does Sam sign the Tooty contract?

The questions are from [this page](http://www.umass.edu/wsp/resources/poisson/problems.html). (Click the blue box for answers).

What Al and Sam say both make sense, so why is Al's answer wrong? Is it because the r=0.2 simply comes from larger samples? Would that mean if we try 100 packages and we observe a different r, it would be even more accurate?

Comment: Glad you asked. The answer in the link is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al is claiming that the table means you should expect $9$ good balloons and one bad balloon in a single package, whereas the table actually means that in a sample of $10$ packages, you should expect $9$ to have no bad balloons, and one to have a single bad balloon.  Al's interpretation is manifestly ridiculous, as it is consistent with a $10\%$ failure rate, not a $1\%$ rate.

The actual experience, $8$ good packages and $2$ with a single defect each, conforms exactly to the $r=.2$ column, that is a rate $.2$ defects per $10-$item sample.

Comment: I see. Al is mixing arguments for a 10-balloon sample with the ones for a 1-balloon sample. For the 1-balloon sample, the correct poisson table is r=0.01. Then the expected number of defect-free balloon for the 10 balloons would be 9.9.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

No wonder you are perplexed. In my view the question in the link is not very well
written and the answer is misleading.  So I will put the 'answer key' aside and try to say something correct.

The evidence on hand, after presumably independently sampling and inflating 100 Tooty balloons, is that we found 2 defectives in 100.

**(1)** An 'Agresti-Coull' 95% confidence interval for the true proportion of defectives
is $(0.0015, 0.0754),$ which includes both $.01$ and $.02.$ So, with such a small sample size, there is not sufficient evidence to distinguish between 1% and 2% failure rates.

**(2)** Testing $H_0: p \le .01$ vs. $H_0: p > .01,$ the P-value is $0.264.$
There no evidence that 2 defectives in 100 is significantly more than 1%.

```
sum(dbinom(2:100, 100, .01))
[1] 0.264238
```

I see no reason to bring the Poisson distribution into this discussion.